# Django keeps applying migrations

Tags: python, django, migration, migrate

This is making me go insane: when I migrate, my django (3.1.1) completes the task, but seems to *forgets* about it.
If I migrate again it will stop because it's trying to reapply the migrations.

Example of the situation:

- I drop db.sqlite3
- I drop everything inside app/migrations (excluded **init**)
- I run makemigrations: no problems.
- I run migrate: no problems.
- I run migrate again: fails (django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "django_content_type" already exists)

Just to make sure I've executed "migrate --plan", confirming that it intends to apply the migrations it just performed. What am I missing here?

---

```
Planned operations:
contenttypes.0001_initial
    Create model ContentType
    Alter unique_together for contenttype (1 constraint(s))
auth.0001_initial
    Create model Permission
    Create model Group
    Create model User
admin.0001_initial
    Create model LogEntry
admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
    Alter field action_time on logentry
admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
    Alter field action_flag on logentry
contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name
    Change Meta options on contenttype
    Alter field name on contenttype
    Raw Python operation
    Remove field name from contenttype
auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
    Alter field name on permission
auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length
    Alter field email on user
auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts
    Alter field username on user
auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null
    Alter field last_login on user
auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002
auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
    Alter field username on user
auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length
    Alter field username on user
auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
    Alter field last_name on user
auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length
    Alter field name on group
auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions
    Raw Python operation ->     Update the content_type of prox…
auth.0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length
    Alter field first_name on user
ipn.0001_initial
    Create model PayPalIPN
ipn.0002_paypalipn_mp_id
    Add field mp_id to paypalipn
ipn.0003_auto_20141117_1647
    Alter field ipaddress on paypalipn
ipn.0004_auto_20150612_1826
    Alter field address_status on paypalipn
    Alter field auth_status on paypalipn
    Alter field case_id on paypalipn
    Alter field case_type on paypalipn
    Alter field charset on paypalipn
    Alter field payer_status on paypalipn
    Alter field payment_cycle on paypalipn
    Alter field payment_status on paypalipn
    Alter field payment_type on paypalipn
    Alter field pending_reason on paypalipn
    Alter field period1 on paypalipn
    Alter field period2 on paypalipn
    Alter field period3 on paypalipn
    Alter field period_type on paypalipn
    Alter field product_name on paypalipn
    Alter field product_type on paypalipn
    Alter field profile_status on paypalipn
    Alter field protection_eligibility on paypalipn
    Alter field reason_code on paypalipn
    Alter field receipt_id on paypalipn
    Alter field receiver_email on paypalipn
    Alter field receiver_id on paypalipn
    Alter field recurring_payment_id on paypalipn
    Alter field transaction_entity on paypalipn
    Alter field txn_id on paypalipn
    Alter field txn_type on paypalipn
ipn.0005_auto_20151217_0948
    Alter field custom on paypalipn
    Alter field transaction_subject on paypalipn
ipn.0006_auto_20160108_1112
    Add field option_selection1 to paypalipn
    Add field option_selection2 to paypalipn
ipn.0007_auto_20160219_1135
    Alter field txn_id on paypalipn
    Alter field txn_type on paypalipn
ipn.0008_auto_20181128_1032
    Alter field flag on paypalipn
    Alter field test_ipn on paypalipn
proxima.0001_initial
    Create model Event
    Create model Member
    Create model Run
    Create model RegistrationTier
    Create model RegistrationQuestion
    Create model RegistrationOption
    Create model Registration
    Create model PaypalInvoice
    Create model AccountingItem
    Create constraint unique run_event on model run
    Create constraint unique question on model registrationquestion
    Create constraint unique option on model registrationoption
    Create constraint unique registraion on model registration
sessions.0001_initial
    Create model Session
```

Comment: Show your `settings.py`

Comment: @Just a name remove all tables from SQL that are created by default by firs migrate.